# Web Scrape by Filling Out Form (with Button) on Website? (Rvest)

Tags: html, r, forms, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to fill out a form on a website: https://www.scwind.com/EligibilityCheck.asp
The website takes an address and tells me which wind zone it's in after I fill out the form.

I've made and submitted the form using Rvest, but I don't know how to see the result.

Sample Code:

```
path <- read_html("https://www.scwind.com/EligibilityCheck.asp")
session <- html_session("https://www.scwind.com/EligibilityCheck.asp")
form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
form
```

Output:

```
> path <- read_html("https://www.scwind.com/EligibilityCheck.asp")
> session <- html_session("https://www.scwind.com/EligibilityCheck.asp")
> form <- html_form(session)[[1]]
> form
<form> 'AppForm' (POST GeocodeCheck.asp)
  <select> 'LocZip' [0/28]
  <select> 'LocCity' [0/1]
  <input Hidden> 'LocNo': 9999
  <input text> 'LocAddr1': 
  <input submit> 'Submit': Determine Eligibility
  <input hidden> 'LocSt': SC
  <input hidden> 'LocCounty':
```

Further Code:

```
form$fields[[5]]$type <- "button"

filled_form <- set_values(form,
                          "LocZip" = "29412",
                          "LocCity" = "JAMES ISLAND (CHARLESTON COUNTY)",
                          "LocAddr1" = "1496 Longspur Dr"
                          )
filled_form
submit_form(session, filled_form)
```

Output:

```
> filled_form
<form> 'AppForm' (POST GeocodeCheck.asp)
  <select> 'LocZip' [1/28]
  <select> 'LocCity' [1/1]
  <input Hidden> 'LocNo': 9999
  <input text> 'LocAddr1': 1496 Longspur Dr
  <input button> 'Submit': Determine Eligibility
  <input hidden> 'LocSt': SC
  <input hidden> 'LocCounty': 

> submit_form(session, filled_form)
Submitting with 'Submit'
<session> https://www.scwind.com/GeocodeCheck.asp
  Status: 500
  Type:   text/html
  Size:   166
```

After this I'm stuck and I don't know how to get the result from the website that you'd normally get after pressing the button.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: It's giving a status of 500 so there's an error there somewhere. Its likely that the site does not use standard HTML forms and more likely uses javascript to get the results. `rvest` cannot run javascript for you. You'd need to use something like [RSelenium](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RSelenium) instead

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick I'll give that a try. I didn't realize that the status line is where it would show an error!